# Import, use and compile a single c++ header file in an ios objective-c project

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm sure the answer is simple but I am facing the following problem ...

I want to use this c++ header file [CAAudioUnitOutputCapturer.h](http://www.f2dd.info/Developer/Examples/CoreAudio/PublicUtility/CAAudioUnitOutputCapturer.h) (there is only a .h file) inside an ios objective-c xcode project.

Could someone tell me how to eliminate compilation errors and give me an example of how to use in Objective-C context?

**Edit**, i got this error :

```
CAAudioUnitOutputCapturer.h:64: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CAAudioUnitOutputCapturer'
```

Comment: What are the errors? How can one tell you how to avoid errors if you don't tell what are the errors?

Comment: Edited with compilation error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, the compiler is trying to build your file as pure Objective C, which is causing these errors. Rename the file you are compiling it into as `myFile.mm` (note the `mm` extension). This will force the compiler to consider it as Objective C++ code, which by virtue of the header you're including, it is.

Answer (score 1):

Any files that use the CAAudioUnitOutputCapturer classes must be Objective-C++ instead of Objective-C. You do that by using a .mm extension instead of .m.

In .mm files you can mix Objective-C classes and C++ classes.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B) is some information regarding Objective-C++.

Answer (score 1):

The files in which you use the `CAAudioUnitOutputCapturer.h` must either be Objective C++ files (default extension `.mm`), or C++ files (extension `.cpp` or `.cc`). If you try to use them in an Objective C (extension `.m`) file you'll get errors, as the compiler is expecting Objective C, not C++.

I do hope you have the object file or library file that contains the (compiled) code for the `CAAudioUnitOutputCapturer` class, otherwise your `.h` file is useless.